# Make RewriteRule to domain with no www

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite `http://www.example.net/anything` to `http://example.net/anything`. But Im looking for universal rule that will work for multiple different domains n-th order.

I made this, but it doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule www\.(.+)$ http://$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Why would you want to go this way? The `www.` should be the canonical address, not the apex.

Comment: @Jack for marketing purposes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(.+)` capture in `RewriteCond` will store the value into `%1`, so that is what you need in the `RewriteRule`.  The `www` (or any part of the domain) will not appear in the value `RewriteRule` processes:

```
# Capture the domain without www into %1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
# Rewrite the whole URI to the %1 domain
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is there any difference between ^www\. and www\. ?

Comment: @Windkiller The `^www` ensures that www occurs at the beginning of the domain. In your original example, it would have permitted it _anywhere_ like in `domain.sub.www.example.com` being redirected to `example.com`. `^` enforces it to be at the start...

Comment: @Windkiller If you actually want that behavior (strip off anything up to and including `www.` no matter where in the domain it resides, remove the `^` but I assumed that you weren't looking for that strange and drastic behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes I wasn't looking for that behavior. I just forgot that www could be also part of domain name.

Answer (score 1):

RewriteRule operates on url Path (not including the domain name):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301]
```